# Using Espresso to stub Intents started during the onCreate of the tested activity

Tags: java, android, testing, android-activity, android-espresso

I am testing an activity that starts another activity during its `onCreate()`. This second activity is started with `startActivityForResult()`, and the main activity then waits for `onActivityResult()`.

I'm trying to use Espresso to test this, attempting to stub the second activity with `intending()`, and verify it occurred using `intended()`.

It appears though that espresso-intents isn't designed to work with intents launched from within the `onCreate()` method ([see the warning in the last paragraphs here](https://jabknowsnothing.wordpress.com/2015/11/05/activitytestrule-espressos-test-lifecycle/)).

Has anyone managed to stub an Intent started from within `onCreate()`, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this working for myself by using the following Kotlin code:

```
@Rule @JvmField
val activityRule: IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> =
        object : IntentsTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java, true, false) {
            override fun beforeActivityLaunched() {
                super.beforeActivityLaunched()
                Intents.init()
                intending(hasComponent(LaunchedFromOnCreateActivity::class.java.name)).respondWith(Instrumentation.ActivityResult(RESULT_OK, null))
            }
            override fun afterActivityLaunched() {
                Intents.release()
                super.afterActivityLaunched()
            }
        }
```

The general idea is that since the lifecycle stuff happens in between beforeActivityLaunched and afterActivityLaunched, you'll need to set up your *intending* there. That said, this doesn't make it possible to do *intended* testing.

Comment: While this isn't what I was hoping for (really want to be able to do intended testing), it does technically answer my question.